# Laravel error: Call to a member function store() on null

Tags: laravel, file, upload

When I tried to send any file I get this message

It's form in home.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ URL::to('/upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="something" >
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <button type="submit" name="button">Upload</button>
</form>
```

It's function inside a Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('something')->store('upload');
    echo $path;
}
```

Comment: check dd($request->all()) in first line of store function image is come from request becuase, error tell you file not coming from request

Comment: array:3 [
  "_token" => "QiqwpAlomMscPemzyYtAtcCCeEKTxPmNzSBJVKmW"
  "button" => null
  "something" => UploadedFile {#208 ▶}
]

Comment: It's strange, but when I renamed the download file everything worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to change controller code like this and see the result:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
$path = $request->something;
echo $path;  }
```